# Tell React Native to use App.tsx instead of App.js

Tags: typescript, react-native

I've scaffolded a project with TypeScript, but my main `index.js` file is referencing `App.js` instead of `App.tsx`.

How can I set my project up so that I am using the TypeScript file (App.tsx) instead of App.js?

Here's my project structure:

[image]

This was scaffolded via `react-native init X --template typescript`

Comment: TS is a language that compiles to JS. That's why you need to compile your .tsx files to .js and point your initial index file to the compiled file.

Comment: @zvona how do I write code in my App.tsx and have it automatically compile to App.js? At the minute, I've got App.js and App.tsx.

Comment: I have a feeling that you've already done this, but just for caution: for instance you have structure for inputFolder **/src/App.tsx** and outputFolder **/dist/App.js**. **index.js** will point to **./dist/App.js**. Then you have TypeScript watcher running (`tsc --watch`) which will compile tsx every time you make changes. The TS behavior is configured inside **tsconfig.json**.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add your relevant folder structure?

I recommend you create a separate source folder with all .ts(x) files, including App.tsx and even an index.ts You compile all these files to a build folder, which means your index.js will also be inside that folder and no longer in your project root.

Then you just adjust build.gradle and AppDelegate.m in the android and ios folders to reference build/index.js in stead of index.js. And don't forget to update any package.json scripts which reference index.js as well (like the build scripts).

I think it makes a lot more sense to keep all JS strictly separated from TS.

Comment: Okay thanks! Like I mentioned: I think it's better to mode App.tsx to your src folder, and then reference the compiled version in your index.js file.