# How do I use App.tsx instead of App.js in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, jsx

I've created a react project with the instructions from it's documentation, which automatically has added the App.js file to the project. My issue is that I want to use App.tsx instead of App.js. For some reason, I am not able to run App.tsx file. How can I fix this, please?

I have read [this question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53884122/tell-react-native-to-use-app-tsx-instead-of-app-js), but I couldn't use it as it didn't make any sense to me since this is my first project with react.

This is my folder structure. [image]

It can be seen on this image, I get an error on the browser when I comment it out the App.js file. [image]

This is the index.js file, which is not changed.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

This is the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "dualnback",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "@types/material-ui": "^0.21.7",
    "atob": "^2.1.2",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "concurrently": "^5.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.0",
    "express-ws": "^4.0.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.8",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0",
    "reactstrap": "^8.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.3",
    "websocket": "^1.0.30",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
    "@types/reactstrap": "^8.2.0",
    "react-router-dom@next":"*"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you change what `index.js` imports as well?  Really both of them should be renamed.

Comment: No I haven't done any changes with index.js file

Comment: Does it say `import {} from "./App.js"` or `import {} from "./App.tsx"` or maybe even `import {} from "./App"`?

Comment: I added the index.js code.

Comment: Any package.json code?

Comment: Try renaming `index.js` to `index.ts` and restarting the react script.  Sometimes the bundler gets mad because you renamed a file out from underneath it but it will still try to use it.

Comment: @keikai how could package.json being related to these two files? I have added the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may just need to install related type libs.

```
npm install --save @types/react @types/react-dom
```

Try it out.

Comment: Almost there! I guess it helped, but I get this error: ./src/App.tsx
  Line 36:10:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

      34 |   }
      35 | 
    > 36 |   public render() {
         |          ^
      37 |     return (
      38 |       <div className="App">
      39 |         <header className="App-header">

Comment: @user10728848 Since you can import your sexy .tsx files now, this question should be closed I guess. The remaining error seems to need some more code in your App.tsx for help.

Comment: It is good to involve some sense of humor to such kind of sexy errors. I think the new error is still related to this App.tsx.

Comment: After recompiling, I get this error now on index.js file. ./src/index.js
  Line 8:21:  Parsing error: '>' expected